# How do I make text appear underneath a div?

Tags: html, css, video

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsUYV.png)

I have a video intro at the top of my website, and I want the website content to be underneath it. But when I added a test line of text, it appears ontop of it. The only thing keeping it from being right at the top is the header. Any help appriciated.

**CSS:**

```
:root {
    --bg-color: #141414;
  --text-color: #fff;
    --default-text-color: #fff;
    --secondary-color: #ff0000;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    color: var(--default-text-color);
    font-family: Rubik;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100%;
    position: static!important;
    top: 0!important;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    transition: all .5s;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: progress;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.loader .logo {
    font-size: 70px;
    color: var(--text-color);
  font-family: 'adrippingmarker', Arial;
}
.privacy-policy {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.privacy-policy:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
.navbar {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
top: 0;
position: sticky;
display: block;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 80;
}
.navbar .nav-btn {
margin-left: 30px;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 70px;
color: var(--text-color);
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
font-weight: 600;
z-index: 81;
}
.navbar .nav-btn-first {
padding: 0;
margin-top: 70px;
color: var(--text-color);
display:inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
font-weight: 600;
z-index: 81;
}
.nav-logo {
  font-family: 'adrippingmarker', Arial;
   padding-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-size: 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--text-color);
z-index: 81;
}
.nav-logo:hover {
background-image: url(../img/logo-hvr.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  color: transparent;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#intro-video-video, .intro-video, #intro-video-alternative {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 683px) {
.nav-btn, .nav-btn-first {
display: none !important;
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar">
<a class="nav-btn-first" href="./gallery.php">Gallery</a> <a class="nav-btn" href="./meet-us.php">Our Team</a> <a class="nav-logo" href="./">misfits.</a> <a class="nav-btn" href="./contact.php">Contact Us</a> <a class="nav-btn" href="./social.php">Socials</a>
</div>
<div class="video-intro">
<video id="intro-video-video" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="./assets/video/bg.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <img id="intro-video-alternative" src="alternative.jpg" />
</video>
</div>
<p> ljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkfljsfjsdhfjhsdkf
</p>
```

**Demo:** https://website.therealmisfits.repl.co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` from `.video-intro` and put it in `.navbar`.

Try this:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.video-intro
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I would like the Navbar to stay at the top of the screen at all times, is it possible using this?
EDIT: Don't worry I sorted it. Thanks for the help!